# Cambiar el estado de un campo cuando es menor a un campo fecha en MySQL

Tags: java, mysql

Hola amigos y disculpen la molestia, me podrían ayudar para saber ¿Cómo cambiar en MySQL el campo estado de mi tabla carritoprestamos cuando sea menor a la fecha actual guardada en mi campo fechas?

Es decir mi tabla "carritoprestamos" cuenta con un campo "FECHAS" y otro campo llamado "ESTADO" quiero que el estado que por defecto es VIGENTE cambie a VENCIDO cuando la fecha sea menor a la actual y que cada vez que haga esta comprobación no me afecte a los estados que ya han sido marcados como AL DIA.

EDITO: (GRACIAS A UN GRAN AMIGO CON EL SIGUIENTE CODIGO ME AYUDA)

```
UPDATE bdprestamo.carritoprestamo SET ESTADO = IF(STR_TO_DATE(fechas,'%d/%m/%YYYY') <  CURDATE(),'VENCIDO','VIGENTE')
```

Solo que yo manejo 3 estados: (VIGENTE,AL DIA,VENCIDO) dentro del campo estado, no se como excluir que tampoco me modifique lo que se encuentre AL DIA.

Es decir que cuando se crea el registro todo esta por defecto en VIGENTE pero si se llega a la fecha guardada de ese registro y no se realiza el pago el estado pase a VENCIDO, pero si se realiza pasara a AL DIA que esto ultimo se ara al momento que el usuario registre el pago.

encontre una solucion justo ahorita 8:41:00 P.M. hablando con el mismo amigo que ya me habia iluminado y la solucion es tan basica y sencilla que consiste solo en lo siguiente:

```
UPDATE bdprestamo.carritoprestamo SET ESTADO = IF(STR_TO_DATE(fechas,'%d/%m/%YYYY') <  CURDATE(),'VENCIDO','VIGENTE') WHERE estado='VIGENTE'
```

con el Where estado='VIGENTE' estoy indicando que dentro de los registros solo me afecte a los que cuentan con esta etiqueta asi ya no afecta a fechas anteriores que contengan la palabra o estado='AL DIA' Saludos a todos!!! y muchas gracias a quienes se tomaron el tiempo en intentar ayudarme!!!

Comment: Validas la fecha y si es menor haces un update, saludos y pon que has intentado si quieres que te ayudemos en codigo.

Comment: Deseas cambiarla ejecutando una consulta, o que se haga automático? Si es lo primero, con un `UPDATE` sería suficiente.

Comment: lo mejor seria en automático, tengo una idea de hacerlo desde la aplicación cada vez que se ejecute pero no creo sea bien el caso.

Comment: Yo personalmente no lo complicaría demasiado. En realidad, no es necesario almacenar "VIGENTE" o "VENCIDO" en la base de datos, ya que es un campo calculado. Podrías hacerlo a nivel de programación, y te facilitaría mucho las cosas.

Comment: ¿Cuál es el tipo de dato de `FECHAS`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Esta es la solucion:

```
UPDATE bdprestamo.carritoprestamo SET ESTADO = IF(STR_TO_DATE(fechas,'%d/%m/%YYYY') <  CURDATE(),'VENCIDO','VIGENTE') WHERE estado='VIGENTE'
```

ya edite para que quede mas explicado, saludos a todos!!!

Answer (score 0):

Intenta con esto:

```
UPDATE carritoprestamos 
SET estado='VENCIDO' 
WHERE estado!= 'AL DIA' 
AND fechas < CURDATE()
```

Comment: me salta lo siguiente  Warning: #1292 Equivocado truncado date valor: '24/05/2021' y cambiando todo a VENCIDO aunque este en una fecha mayor.

Comment: ¿Podrías colocar el `CREATE TABLE` completo? De preferencia con algunos `INSERT` de ejemplo, para poder ayudarte mejor. En teoría, con los datos que brindaste, esta consulta debería funcionar.

Comment: donde o como hago eso amigo? ya tengo el archivo pero donde lo pego? porque lo quise colocar como comentario pero excede el limite de caracteres.

Comment: UPDATE carritoprestamos 
SET estado='VENCIDO' 
WHERE estado!= 'AL DIA' 
AND CONVERT(fechas, DATE) < CONVERT(now(), DATE);              Con eso funcionara

Comment: No amigo, ejecute tal cual pero me cambia todo a VENCIDO aun cuando las fechas son mayores a las de hoy.

Comment: Ahorita sigo trabajando para encontrar una solución, el detalle esta que son 3 estados los que estarán presentes en la bd tanto VIGENTE que es el que esta por defecto ya que todo registro empezara de esta forma, después cada que pase la fecha marcada de ese registro pase a VENCIDO y solo pasara al estado AL DIA pero por parte del usuario a la hora de que registre el cobro, estoy pensando hacerlo desde el propio JAVA aunque mas quería esta parte desde la propia BD, colocarlo vigente y al día no es el problema, el problema es el de vencido.